# RanorexPath Attribute does not match

Tags: xpath, ranorex

Problem: Attribute does not match the specified value:

`Validation Failure: Attribute 'Text' of element for item 'CommonRepository.MyApp.InfoTab.StatusWaitingForNewRound' does not match the specified value (actual='Status: Waiting for start', expected='Status: Waiting for a new round').`

My path for this repo item: `.//text[@automationid='textGameStatus' and @text='Status:           Waiting for a new round' or @text='Status:           Waiting for start']`

As you see I am using **"or"**, hence I expect it to accept either one or another and if there are neither then it should fail, but in reality it does not work this way.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Ranorex path just searches for the element in your application. Ranorex finds the element in case it has the text value "Status: Waiting for a new round" or "Status: Waiting for start". In the validation step you are validating against an specific value (Status: Waiting for a new round). In my opinion, waiting for the start and waiting for a new round are two different cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider 'Status: Waiting for' to be a correct value, why not just use the starts with (>) symbol:

```
//text[@automationid='textGameStatus' and @text>'Status: Waiting for']
```

Or you could use regex (~) symbol:

```
//text[@automationid='textGameStatus' and @text~'Status: Waiting for.+']
```

Or you could just create a repo item with //text[@automationid='textGameStatus'] and read its @text attribute then compare it to predefined list of strings (or regex in user code.

Don't forget to validate that you repo item works for all supported cases using the spy.

If you repo item is correctly mapped, it should work as expected.

Hope it helps!